# Matlab finding tangent of two curves

Tags: matlab, math

For A Homework Project I have to find the point at which two curves are tangent.

I wrote the following script but it gives me an error:

```
Warning: 2 equations in 1 variables.
```

I do not understand this warning, but my teacher said it should not be there.

Here is My Script:

```
syms x y;

y1 = x^3-3*x+4;
y2 = 3*(x^2-x);

y1_prime = diff(y1);
y2_prime = diff(y2);

x_point = solve(y1 == y2, x1_prime == x2_prime);

slope = subs(y1_prime, x, x_point);

y_point = subs(y1, x,x_point);

tangent_line = solve(y - y_point == slope*(x - x_point), y); 

fprintf('The equation for the tangent line is: %s\n', string(tangent_line));
```

Please Help. Thank You :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two equations to solve.  The first one is the intersection of the two curves:

```
x^3-3*x+4 = 3*(x^2-x)
```

and the second one requires that the slopes match at the point of intersection:

```
3*x^2-3 = 3*(2*x-1)
```

So you have two equations in one unknown, x, which can be solved for x for this case, but in general you may not be able to find a solution.

Comment: I was thinking it was a question about MATLAB.

Comment: Yes, it is a question about MATLAB. I was explaining why the warning "Warning: 2 equations in 1 variables." makes sense.

Comment: I see.. I think MATLAB might be a little overkill for this one anyway.

Comment: I guess the warning makes sense, but is there a way to go about it so that there's no warning?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the warning. The symbolic solver initially wouldn't know that your two equations in one variable does actually have a solution.